Use BotFramework-WebChat in a React app with customization
I want to build a Chat bot in a custom React application (public web site).
I have a few questions about the usage of https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat:

Can we have an interface like in https://www.intercom.com?. An icon appears in the bottom corner of the web site and if you click, you open the chatbot interface.
Is it possible to fully customize the web chat UI?
Is it possible to change the code of the chatbot in our application?
Is it possible to change the code of the web chat in order to call our APIs that will receive a prompt and generate a response?
Is it possible to change the Html and CSS?

If this is possible, can you provide links to documentation on how to to this?
Thanks
I am expecting to have a full customizable chat bot.
